# Create a http proxy in php for uploading images using 'iframe'

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, proxy, cross-domain

**Use Case**: I am working on an image uploader which uses [ajax upload](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) function.I want to upload images to a subdomain user creates on the website.For example,when the user creates a domain on the website I copy a php script for uploading images to the new domain viz `image-cropping.php`.I want to send a request to this file when the user uploads any image to his domain.

**Issue**:
When I try to upload an image I get `Error: Permission denied to access property 'readyState'`.My calling **js file** is on `xyz.google.com` and the upload php script is on `abc.google.com`.

**Research**
After doing some googling and research I learnt javascript won't allow to **send request cross domain** and it needs a http proxy to handle this.Here is the code I have tried.The script to run the ajax uploader.In action I have the path to file on other domain(the path is built dynamically).

```
   new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'includes/modules/domain_creation/proxy.php',
        name: 'image',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
            if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF)$/.test(ext))){ 
                alert('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
            $('#thumbImg').html('<img src="http://localhost/gobiggi_VS_2_2/images/appImages/imageLoader.png" />');
        },
```

1) Am I doing it in the right way(working on it for first time)?Is the **proxy actually needed**?
2)How and where can I **set the proxy** so that the error permission can be negotiated?
3)What security issues does it open up(Is it safe?If not what's an alternative)?Any pointers or suggestions would be helpful for me.
Thank you for your time.

**Update:**
I am using this proxy [script](https://github.com/eslachance/php-transparent-proxy) for uploading the image.Part of the code is

```
   $domainUsername = $_SESSION['domainUsername'];
   $domainNameWeb = $_SESSION['domainName'];
   //$fileParameterProxy = $_FILES['image'];
   //Destination URL: Where this proxy leads to the upload script
     $destinationURL = 'http://www.'.$domainNameWeb.'/'.$domainUsername.'/upload.php';
   //The only domain from which requests are authorized.
   $RequestDomain = 'abc.net';
```

Now I don't get the `Error for permission` but I am not able to get the image on to the server.When I try to do `print_r($_FILES)` I get a blank array on my upload script.

I believe I am missing something!!Can someone please correct?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2) You have to set your proxy as action, because that is the place where you are allowed to upload the files. The proxy then will do the request to the other domain, where it can send the files to.

3) Depends on your proxy implementation. You should avoid to store the files locally or execute/include anything from user input, like always when writing php scripts. Directly send the tmp file to your destination server, this will also be the fastest implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs,but can you help me out how the request would be?Also,I learned http requests not being safe and using `https` instead.Can you throw some light on it please?

Comment: Which kind of proxy are you using? Where is it stored? http is not encrypted, https is. But if you need it depends on the data you are sending. Is it something sensitive?

Comment: Currently I am not using any proxy.Actually working on proxies for the first time!! :P I tried sending a plain `http` request as in the question above and got the error mentioned.The function specifically needs to **upload images** stored on the user domain(User will create his own domain from the site).The information is somewhat critical as user data is invloved in it.

Comment: If the data is critical you should https. But first things first: You have to create a proxy on your current domain for your usecase. You won't be able to upload directly to the other domains.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs till now.One final question I have is what changes exactly I have to make in the `action` for setting the proxy?Currently I have the url of the upload file residing on the user domain.How can I call it using a proxy?

Comment: You have to change the action to call your proxy and submit your final url (user domain) in an extra parameter or code it in the proxy if possible.

Comment: I am updating the code with the proxy I worked on.Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I couldn't review the full proxy script, but the readme says it is supporting _POST and _GET. No mentioning of _FILES. So I think it's not supporting that.

Comment: ok!!I guess I missed it,because I am not getting any error but just not getting the image name.You should be right!!Can you point me to an image proxy if possible?

Comment: `POST` should allow us to upload right??We generally do a form `POST` with `multipart/formdata` to have something uploaded!!Not sure why it doesn't work here.Can you please add some explanation?Thank you

Comment: Yes it's uploaded via the post method, but the PHP _POST array only contains text data, no uploaded files. these data is stored in _FILES

Comment: Can you suggest changes to achieve it??or some other way in which I can make it work.it would be a great help for me!!thank you

Comment: Try to find a php proxy, which also supports file uploads.

Comment: Yes I tried but not getting the desired results!!!Neither I am able to correctly modify the code nor able to find the right script!!Stuck pretty badly here!