# PHP, How to Redirect/Forward HTTP Request with header and body?

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP page, main.php which is on server 1.

I have a PHP page main.php (same page, different code) on server 2.

main.php is a WebService.

I would like to forward the full HTTP request made to server 1, to server 2,
so that when a user sends an HTTP request to main.php (server 1), it would get the response from main.php on server 2.

I would like the request made to server 2 to be exactly like the original request to server 1.

I take the Http Request data via:

```
$some_param  = $_REQUEST['param']
$body =file_get_contents('php://input');
```

and lets say i have

```
$server1_url = "11111";
$server2_url = "22222";
```

The motivation for this is, i have a production server and a staging server, i would like to direct some traffic to the new server to test the new functionality on the staging server.

How do i redirect the request with all the data or "cloning" the full request, sending it to the new server and returning the new response?

Thanks for your help!

p.s i tried using php curl, but i dont understand how it works, also i found all kinds of answers, but none forward the Requests params and the body.

Again thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a simple PHP transparent proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091022/how-do-i-write-a-simple-php-transparent-proxy)

Comment: what does proxy have anything to do with this? also i dont see any applicable answer on the question you quoted, do you?  thanks.

Comment: "forward the full http request made to server 1, to server2". That's a **PROXY**.

Comment: is it 100% necessary you need to do this in php?

Comment: @Marc B. you are correct, sorry... and still i cant find nothing i can use.

Comment: @anurupr - what do u suggest? i just want to get it done.

Comment: well for your requirement you need to setup the first server as a proxy for the 2nd server . this is exactly what @MarcB is talking about. but its not necessary you need to do it in php . you can do it on the server level which is more efficient as the number of levels of processing is reduced. but before i proceed . are both servers running apache?

Comment: @anurupr yes both server running apache, php is not a must, your solution sounds better, the only question will i be able to control who get redirected and whos not? (according to user_id for example?)

Comment: then you should look into the following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100830/apache-forwarding-request-to-another-server and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html . It does have access control but I'm afraid I cannot help you more with that. you will need to do more reading and testing and get back to us on that.

Comment: ok, im working on a php solution because i need to control which users get routed where, once il know how i will publish it.(i now have a not fully tested solution)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is the solution i have found (there might be better)

```
 public static function getResponse ($url,$headers,$body)
    {
        $params = '?' . http_build_query($headers);

        $redirect_url = $url . $params;

        $ch = curl_init($redirect_url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if (!isset($response))
            return null;
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 33):

If you have access to the Apache server config you can create a virtualhost with the following settings:

```
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass / http://remotesite.domain.tld/
ProxyPassReverse / http://remotesite.domain.tld/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain remotesite.domain.tld proxysite.tld
```

You'll need to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http for this.
Substitute remotesite.domain.tld to the site you forward to, and proxysite.tld to the forwarder.

If you don't have access to the server config files, you can still do in php, by manually setting up curl and forward everything.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

/* Set it true for debugging. */
$logHeaders = FALSE;

/* Site to forward requests to.  */
$site = 'http://remotesite.domain.tld/';

/* Domains to use when rewriting some headers. */
$remoteDomain = 'remotesite.domain.tld';
$proxyDomain = 'proxysite.tld';

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$ch = curl_init();

/* If there was a POST request, then forward that as well.*/
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site . $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$headers = getallheaders();

/* Translate some headers to make the remote party think we actually browsing that site. */
$extraHeaders = array();
if (isset($headers['Referer'])) 
{
    $extraHeaders[] = 'Referer: '. str_replace($proxyDomain, $remoteDomain, $headers['Referer']);
}
if (isset($headers['Origin'])) 
{
    $extraHeaders[] = 'Origin: '. str_replace($proxyDomain, $remoteDomain, $headers['Origin']);
}

/* Forward cookie as it came.  */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $extraHeaders);
if (isset($headers['Cookie']))
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $headers['Cookie']);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

if ($logHeaders)
{
    $f = fopen("headers.txt", "a");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

$headerArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $headers);

/* Process response headers. */
foreach($headerArray as $header)
{
    $colonPos = strpos($header, ':');
    if ($colonPos !== FALSE) 
    {
        $headerName = substr($header, 0, $colonPos);
        
        /* Ignore content headers, let the webserver decide how to deal with the content. */
        if (trim($headerName) == 'Content-Encoding') continue;
        if (trim($headerName) == 'Content-Length') continue;
        if (trim($headerName) == 'Transfer-Encoding') continue;
        if (trim($headerName) == 'Location') continue;
        /* -- */
        /* Change cookie domain for the proxy */
        if (trim($headerName) == 'Set-Cookie')
        {
            $header = str_replace('domain='.$remoteDomain, 'domain='.$proxyDomain, $header);
        }
        /* -- */
        
    }
    header($header, FALSE);
}

echo $body;

if ($logHeaders)
{
    fclose($f);
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

EDIT:

And of course the script must be in the root directory of a (sub)domain.
And you should have a .htaccess that rewrites everything to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The script *forwards* to the $site, instead of keeping the proxy domain in the URL.

Comment: The script works very well. Just one thing if it helps someone. The original server was redirecting page to another, lets say from http to https. As script sets headers for content after fetching via curl, I had to add one more line to avoid redirect loop. `if (trim($headerName) == 'Location') continue;` Please check if you can update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, to get data from another server even if it redirects, I had to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to get data and display.

Comment: Thank you very much. worked perfectly. Had to disable ssl check.

Comment: I tried to forward an xmlrpc GET request to an old joomla 1.5 site, that supports xmlrpc. However, despite the suggested code completes successfully (i.e. I see 200 OK in headers.txt), the response is: XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1.
I will appreciate any input/ideas on how to resolve the error.

Comment: I found that GET body should be copied as:
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $entityBody);

Then xmlrpc works!

Comment: I tried it out, and for me I had to change `$site = 'http://remotesite.domain.tld/';` to `$site = 'http://remotesite.domain.tld';` (without ending slash)

Comment: Hi, I try this to a remotesite domain which is using asp net. But I got error below 

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.

Any solutions how to fix this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code by Rehmat and Calmarius and made a few changes so now it handles multiple fields with same name like

```
<input type="text" name="example[]">
<input type="text" name="example[]">
<input type="text" name="example[]">
```

and to upload files too, including multiple files that use the same field name.

here is goes:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

class proxy {
    private $logHeaders     = false;
    
    /* Site to forward requests to.  */
    private $site           = 'http://redirectToSite';
    /* Domains to use when rewriting some headers. */
    private $remoteDomain   = 'redirectToSite';
    private $proxyDomain    = 'yourproxydomain.com';

    public function __construct() {
        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $ch = curl_init();

        /* If there was a POST request, then forward that as well.*/
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $post   = $this->sanitizePostFields($_POST);
            $files  = $this->sanitizeFiles($_FILES);
            if ($files) {
                $post = array_merge($post, $files);
            }
            
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            /*
            // this is enough if not uploading files
            curl_setopt(
                $ch,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                http_build_query($_POST)
            );
            */
        }
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->site . $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

        $headers = getallheaders();

        /*
            Translate some headers to make the remote party think we
            actually browsing that site.
        */
        $extraHeaders = array();
        if (isset($headers['Referer'])) {
            $extraHeaders[] = 'Referer: '. str_replace(
                $this->proxyDomain,
                $this->remoteDomain,
                $headers['Referer']
            );
        }
        if (isset($headers['Origin'])) {
            $extraHeaders[] = 'Origin: '. str_replace(
                $this->proxyDomain,
                $this->remoteDomain,
                $headers['Origin']
            );
        }

        /*
            Forward cookie as it came.
        */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $extraHeaders);
        if (isset($headers['Cookie'])) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $headers['Cookie']);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        if ($this->logHeaders) {
            $f = fopen("headers.txt", "a");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
        }

        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($response, $header_size);

        $headerArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $headers);

        /* Process response headers. */
        foreach($headerArray as $header) {
            $colonPos = strpos($header, ':');
            if ($colonPos !== FALSE) {
                $headerName = substr($header, 0, $colonPos);

                /*
                    Ignore content headers, let the webserver decide how to
                    deal with the content.
                */
                if (trim($headerName) == 'Content-Encoding') continue;
                if (trim($headerName) == 'Content-Length') continue;
                if (trim($headerName) == 'Transfer-Encoding') continue;
                
                //if (trim($headerName) == 'Location') continue;
                
                /* -- */
                /* Change cookie domain for the proxy */
                if (trim($headerName) == 'Set-Cookie') {
                    $header = str_replace(
                        'domain='.$this->remoteDomain,
                        'domain='.$this->proxyDomain,
                        $header
                    );
                }
                /* -- */
                
                if (trim($headerName) == 'Location') {
                    $header = str_replace(
                        $this->remoteDomain,
                        $this->proxyDomain,
                        $header
                    );
                }
            }
            
            header($header, FALSE);
        }

        echo $body;

        if ($this->logHeaders) {
            fclose($f);
        }
        
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    private function sanitizePostFields($post, $fieldName = '') {
        if (empty($post)) { return false; }
        if (!is_array($post)) { return false; }
        
        $result = [];
        
        foreach ($post as $k => $v) {
            if (is_string($v)) {
                $result[($fieldName ? "{$fieldName}[{$k}]" : $k)] = $v;
            }
            elseif (is_array($v)) {
                $result = array_merge(
                    $result,
                    $this->sanitizePostFields($v, $k)
                );
            }
        }
        
        return $result;
    }

    private function sanitizeFiles($files) {
        if (empty($files)) { return false; }
        if (!is_array($files)) { return false; }
        
        $result = [];
        
        foreach ($files as $k => $v) {
            if (empty($v['name'])) { continue; }
            
            if (is_array($v['name'])) {
                // more than one file using the same name field[]
                $nFields = count($v['name']);
                for ($i = 0; $i < $nFields; $i++) {
                    if (empty($v['tmp_name'][$i])) { continue; }
                    $curl_file_upload = new CURLFile(
                        $v['tmp_name'][$i],
                        $v['type'][$i],
                        $v['name'][$i]
                    );
                    $result["{$k}[{$i}]"] = $curl_file_upload;
                }
            }
            else {
                $curl_file_upload = new CURLFile(
                    $v['tmp_name'],
                    $v['type'],
                    $v['name']
                );
                $result[$k] = $curl_file_upload;
            }
        }
        
        return $result;
    }
    
}

$proxy = new proxy();
```