# PHP: Is it possible to send a raw copy of the POST request to a new URL?

Tags: php, post

I'm getting an instant payment notification but need it to go to two places! I only have the option for one link, so is it possible to get the raw post data via PHP and send it on to a new link?

[image: Sort of like this]

Is a process like this possible without knowing all the details of the POST beforehand? Is there a generic function to get all post data and is it then possible to send an identical request with that information?

Not looking for any code, just a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945879/how-to-get-body-of-a-post-in-php)

Comment: Perhaps setting up a proxy is easier than writing your own script. That said, you might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437548/php-how-to-redirect-forward-http-request-with-header-and-body

Comment: @RiggsFolly, if it's marked as duplicate i think my link is a better duplicate. Since the OP is asking for forwarding an actual request, which is answered there.

Comment: Thanks guys! Both links are very helpful. @Webber

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't agree that Dharman's post is a duplicate of mine since it would also have to answer the second half of how to take the data and send it back out as a post. IMO Webber's link answers both sides of the question for me. Sorry I couldn't find it myself!

Comment: I have Re-Opened

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997 <-- This answer can lead you to the resolution. It' just a matter of adapting things. Implementing such a function, then you can call it many times changing params like `method` and `action`, which means you can have an unique form posted to many destinations after a single click on a button.